# React component background doesn't zoom with page elements

Tags: css, reactjs, background

EDIT for comment:

As you can see, the `background-size: cover` selector seems to affect zoom capacity in some way. With this selector deselected, I am able to zoom the background as per normal.

[image]

---

I have a react app with a background, when I zoom in the webpage the background remains static and doesn't zoom with the rest of the elements. This means that at a certain zoom level the background only takes up the top half of the screen.

Here is an example. As you can see the blue annotated areas are where the element is bigger than the background and the background no longer fills the screen:

[image]

Here is the react component:

```
    <div id="app" className="d-flex h-100 flex-column home-background">
        <Provider value={providing}>
          <div className="app-dash">
            <LoggedInNav />
            <ChallengeModal/>
            <TeamsModal/>
            <ComingSoonModal/>
            <hr id="hr-below-nav"/>
            <div className="transition-group-dash">
              <TransitionGroup>
                <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="fade" timeout={100}>
                    <Router>
                      <Route path="/app/cat" component={Categories} />
                      <Route path="/app/faq" component={Faq} />
                      <Route path="/app/contact" component={Contact} />
                      <Route path="/app/logout" component={Logout} />
                    </Router>
                </CSSTransition>
              </TransitionGroup>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Provider>
    </div>
```

Here is the css where the image is set:

```
.home-background{
  background-image: url("./assets/backgrounds/loading-background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  height:100%;
}
```

Some other CSS I have added to make the background fill out properly at a normal zoom level:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400&display=swap');
body{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
}

#root{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html, body, #app, #app>div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way to workaround this? Apparently zoom is for accessibility and was never designed to retain layout, so I feel like this might just be the default behaviour. However, I don't want to assume and just deploy it if I can make it more production ready.

Comment: It's difficult to tell only by your code here. The CSS looks okay but as you have many components in the tree it's not clear what styles they could have. Such effect usually happens when there is a floating somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Azu hmmmm ok so floating could be causing this issue. I definitely use floating in some of the modal components and I'm still using a global CSS for dev. So maybe my first concern should really be encapsulating that into components (which we is slated for early next year). Thanks :)

Comment: Try to clearfix the floats. Try to notice if the background actually resizes when zooming but doesn't reach the bottom of the page. Is that the case?

Comment: @Azu it's hard to tell... it definitely doesn't resize with the rest of the page. It does reach the bottom at normal zoom tho. Doesn't touch the bottom when zoomed. I'll check the floats and see what happens.

Comment: @Azu see my edit on possible cause

Comment: What I can immediately see is that 'cover' is not applied at all.

Comment: could you copy the HTML as rendered in the Dev tools and the CSS too, and place them here to have a look. I suppose you cannot show the real code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237287/discussion-between-azu-and-bitshift).